How to create a halo effect similar to a light on an object?
I use textures to illuminate the entire scene and model.

Now there is a question, how to make a part of the model (with white text) produce a halo effect similar to a light?

If possible, how many methods can we achieve it?
I really hope for your help, thank you!
